# Can PHP get the verbose output of pg_query('ANALYZE VERBOSE table_name;')?

Tags: php, postgresql

When I run this command in `psql`:

```
ANALYZE VERBOSE table_name;
```

I get output like this:

```
INFO:  analyzing "public.table_name"
INFO:  "table_name": scanned 4 of 4 pages, containing 426 live rows and 18 dead rows; 426 rows in sample, 426 estimated total rows
ANALYZE
```

If I run the same command from within a PHP application, can I access the same output?

```
pg_query('ANALYZE VERBOSE table_name;');
```

Comment: What version of PHP / Postgres are you using? I ran a quick test in my environment and did not find anything in the results, notices, or errors using PHP 5.5.7 and PostgreSQL 9.3.3

Comment: PHP 5.3.8 and PostgreSQL 9.2.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
exec("psql dbname -c \"analyze verbose table_name\" 2>&1", $output);
```

2>&1 is necessary because the first two lines is put into stderr, without this you will get "ANALYZE" only.

Comment: Is calling out to psql necessary?

Comment: I think so, using pg_query() will return a resource with zero row inside. This is the only way I know can get the expected result.